# Why "ni" instead of "no" in the sentence "Ni siquiera puedo dormir"?

Tags: traducción, gramática, conjunciones

> Ni siquiera puedo dormir

Which is the translation for

> I cannot even sleep.

So I was wondering why cannot it be

> No siquiera puedo dormir.

How does 'No' became 'Ni' in the above sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**neither** and **not even** aren't equal in spanish language.
Normally these mean **tampoco** and **ni siquiera**

> I didn't even like these, neither those.

Here we say "ni siquiera me gustaron estos, tampoco esos."
If we want to use **ni siquiera**, we need to put

> I didn't even like these, not even those.

Which means "ni siquiera me gustaron estos, ni siquiera esos."
However this sounds weird in spanish since we normally say the first sentence I put or

> I didn't like these, not even those.

Which is "no me gustaron estos, ni siquiera esos."

The easiest way to differentiate **ni** from **no** in spanish is when we use **no** before a **ni**, this one comes immediately to state we don't want this stuff nor the other.

Answer (score 2):

Because **Ni** means **[Nor](http://www.spanishdict.com/translate/ni)** or **Neither**

**Ni siquiera / Nisiquiera** means **neither** or **not even**

An example of the difference with rough translation

> No me gustan los tacos sucios a mi.

That is very straightforward... I don't like dirty tacos, but when you say this

> Ni me gustan los tacos sucios a mi.

It implies that I don't like other things.  Ni functions as a [copulative conjunction](http://grammarist.com/grammar/conjunctions/) meaning that it is used to aggregate, to add to the list of things.

> A mi no me gustan los tacos sucios **ni** la basura mojada **ni** la carne perro **ni** el perder de dinero

It's also somewhat of an equivalent of the English **me neither**, although there is a word *tampoco* that does mean that already, I'm trying to make a point here.

> A mi no me gustan los tacos sucios
>
> Ni a mi

English phrases such as

> I ordered an expensive beer and I didn't even get to drink it. :*)

can be translated to this

> Ordené una cerveza cara y ni pude tomarla.

and

> Not even George Washington liked dirty tacos.

translates to

> Ni siquiera a George Washington le gustaban los tacos sucios

There are more descriptive definitions [here](http://buscon.rae.es/drae/srv/search?val=ni)